# Unrecognized platform name iOS in Lotti

Tags: ios, lottie

I have been building my project completely fine over the last two days and then I opened the project this morning and tried to build it and got the error

`Unrecognized platform name iOS` with the following code.

```
  if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
  if ([UIView userInterfaceLayoutDirectionForSemanticContentAttribute:self.semanticContentAttribute] == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft) {
      diff = diff * -1;
  }
}
```

The error is coming from a project in my pods: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today when using pod version 2.1.4 on Xcode 8.3.3. This version (2.1.4) works fine con Xcode 9.1. This is because:

The line that has the error

```
if (@available(iOS 9.0, *))
```

is using @available compiler flag, only available in Xcode 9 according to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

**So, either you upgrade to Xcode 9 or downgrade the pod version to 2.1.3 as this code was inserted in this latest version.**

Answer (score 0):

I have pod version 1.7.0.beta.3 and also that error still displays
but the best solution is `@"String"` so the code will be:

```
if(@"available(iOS 9.0, *)")
```

Comment: Your change would just disable the check - the evaluation would always be true because you are now checking the string rather than os version.